# C# - reading and displaying HTML from resources

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, resources, razor

.NET 4, VS 2010, C#, MVC 3.

In my resource file, I have:

```
First line.<p />Second line.
```

I'm reading it from the view via Razor:

```
@Translations.Example
```

But my p's stay p's - in other words, they don't get rendered as HTML.

Why?

Comment: It's a good point, for security reason, that content is rendered encoded by default. This will avoid a lot of JS code injection attack. When you use @Html.Raw, you take the decision to render HTML raw content... then you also have ensured the HTML rendered is safe. In comparison, if rendering wasn't encoded by default, you would have to ensure content is safe each time a user input something, you render somewhere... painful and risky as a good proportion of developers "forget" to ensure user input safety

Comment: Basically, only call Html.Raw when you know the content is safe.

Answer (score 19):

Do

```
@Html.Raw(Translations.Example)
```

Answer (score 6):

try to use `Raw` extension method

```
@Html.Raw(Translations.Example)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:    @Html.Raw(YourResourceFile.KeyInTheResourceFile)